# Save Syncfusion Scheduler Appointment to Database

Tags: angular, scheduler, syncfusion

**Hi**
Can anybody please guide me the process to adding a new appointment to DB via the Save button of Editor.
Like when I click on any Cell and add the info in Editor and then Click on Save, it will add the appointment in Calendar, I want to save that appointment to Database as well

Also the approach of adding invdividual appointment is the correct one that Syncfusion recommends as I have seen an example where there is an Add button on top of Scheduler ( defined via ng-template) and you can write code in there to call the relevant API

**Thanks**

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what framework or library you use but I tried to solve this problem in `Ract.js.`

To do this, you need to use the `popupClose` property to which you will pass your save function.

The code below allowed me to retrieve the data entered in the event editor and insert it into an array :

```
const save = 'e-event-create e-text-ellipsis e-control e-btn e-lib e-flat e-primary';
const saveEvent = 'e-control e-btn e-lib e-primary e-event-save e-flat';
const moreDetails = 'e-event-details e-text-ellipsis e-control e-btn e-lib e-flat';
const closePopup = (args) => {
  const classNameSave = args.event.target.className

  if (args.event.target.className !== moreDetails) {
    if (classNameSave === save || classNameSave === saveEvent) {
      scheduleData.push({
        Id: scheduleData.length + 1,
        Subject: args.data.Subject,
        Location: args.data.Location,
        StartTime: args.data.StartTime,
        EndTime: args.data.EndTime
      })
      console.log(scheduleData);
    }
  }
}
```

After that, you can pass the function to the property as shown below:

```
return (
  <div className='m-2 md:m-10 mt-24 p-2 md:p-10 bg-white rounded-3xl'>

    <ScheduleComponent
      popupClose={closePopup}
      height='650px'
      eventSettings={{ dataSource: scheduleData }}
      selectedDate={new Date(2021, 0, 10)}
    >
      <Inject services={[...]} />
    </ScheduleComponent>
  </div>
 )
```

Here is the complete code :

```
import React from 'react';
import { ScheduleComponent, Day, Week, WorkWeek, Month, Agenda, Resize, DragAndDrop, Inject } from "@syncfusion/ej2-react-schedule";
import { scheduleData } from "yourDatasource";

const Calendar = () => {

  const save = 'e-event-create e-text-ellipsis e-control e-btn e-lib e-flat e-primary';
  const saveEvent = 'e-control e-btn e-lib e-primary e-event-save e-flat';
  const moreDetails = 'e-event-details e-text-ellipsis e-control e-btn e-lib e-flat';

  const closePopup = (args) => {
    const classNameSave = args.event.target.className

    if (args.event.target.className !== moreDetails) {
      if (classNameSave === save || classNameSave === saveEvent) {
        scheduleData.push({
          Id: scheduleData.length + 1,
          Subject: args.data.Subject,
          Location: args.data.Location,
          StartTime: args.data.StartTime,
          EndTime: args.data.EndTime
        })
        console.log(scheduleData);
      }
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className='m-2 md:m-10 mt-24 p-2 md:p-10 bg-white rounded-3xl'>
 
      <ScheduleComponent
        popupClose={closePopup}
        height='650px'
        eventSettings={{ dataSource: scheduleData }}
        selectedDate={new Date(2021, 0, 10)}
      >
        <Inject services={[...]} />
      </ScheduleComponent>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Calendar
```

Warmly

Answer (score 0):

```
if (args.event.target.className !== moreDetails) {
      if (classNameSave === save || classNameSave === saveEvent) {
        scheduleData.push({
          Id: scheduleData.length + 1,
          Subject: args.data.Subject,
          Location: args.data.Location,
          StartTime: args.data.StartTime,
          EndTime: args.data.EndTime
        })
        console.log(scheduleData);
      }
    }
  }
```

The StartTime: args.data.StartTime
and EndTime: args.data.EndTime
are not providing the data...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).